# A workaround to building dynamic multilingual Wix pages?

Tags: multilingual, velo

There's no "out of the box" option to create multilingual **dynamic** pages in Wix platform.

My idea is to have a single data table where I would store the same data in multiple languages (separate columns: Title EN, Title DE etc.). I would then trigger one or the other data column based on the language a user chooses to view the page in.

Has anyone had the same issue on Wix and maybe manages to find a workouround using some Java script magic?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are suggesting should work fine. You can either store all the languages in a single collection or have a collection per language. I think a collection per language would probably be easier if you keep the field names the same because you could use the same exact queries, just on a different collection.

Then you can use the [currentLanguage](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-window/multilingual-obj/currentlanguage) property to determine which collection to query.